# Executing Spark on yarn cluster mode AccessControlException

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have some Spark code that analyzes an Input dataset which is in a CSV file.

When I run it in cluster mode I am getting the following error (in local mode it works fine up to now).

My questions are:

1. Does a local variable affect the parallel execution in different workers?
2. I am using localfile as an input. Do I have to use HDFS file?

I believed the RDD is parallelized and the inputfile could be stored in a local file system.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=xxx, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:216) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:145) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6599) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6581) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6533) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4337) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4307) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4280) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:853) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.mkdirs(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:321) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:601) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619) 
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root directory `inode="/"` is owned by `hdfs` user of `supergroup` group with Unix permissions of `drwxr-xr-x` (755)

Your `user=xxx` is apparently not the `hdfs` user nor is in the `superuser` group....

This is all Unix permission based, and has really nothing to do with Spark.

Your solutions are

1. (Preferred) Learn how to add your `xxx` user to the `superuser` group **and** copy these group permissions across all datanodes and namenodes in the cluster.
2. Run your code as the `hdfs` user.
3. (**Last resort**) Make everything in HDFS 775 or 777 permission

---

To answer your questions.

> Does a local variable affect the parallel execution in different workers?

All Spark executors have their own, isolated local variables. Broadcast variables are those that you must setup to be shared.

> Do I have to use HDFS file?

No, but if you don't, all your Spark workers must be able to read the exact same file on their own local filesystem.
Or you can setup some other shared FileSystem like S3, (S)FTP, or NFS.